What causes these oscillations at high frequencies in a Sallen-Key low pass filter?
I constructed a Sallen-Key low pass filter with a cutoff frequency of around 48 Hertz.  When I generated the Bode plot, I got these weird oscillations of the phase at really high frequencies. I've tried searching why online but I've come up short.
Why is this happening?


I'll redraw it for you so it becomes clearer: -


The yellow horizontal line is where +180 (below) becomes -180 (above)
I've superimposed redlines where the phase would linearly go if the meter had the facility


I think the problem is compounded somewhat by the particularly unhelpful vertical scale for the phase plot. 49° per division is just ridiculous.

I still dont get it sorry. Does this mean that once it crosses 180 degrees it resets and has to start from -180 degrees ?

@KrishnavBhatnagar yes, that's exactly what happens. There are only 360 degrees and phase lagging refers to a phase angle of zero to -180. Beyond -180 you can say the measured signal compared to the reference signal is leading (range 0 to +180). So, your device measures between +180 degrees and -180 degrees it seems. It's still a full circle but, what you see as discontinuities are not.

If you are loading the op amp output with the high capacitance of a coax cable, rather than using a low-capacitance 10:1 probe, that capacitance could be causing the observed instability.
